# Create a model Using Spatial types EF CORE

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i know that the entity framework team has delayed the spatial types support, but is there a way to tell entity framework to create a column of Geography type for a specified entity?

i'll make the querys using the .FromSql(String) method, but i want teh model build completely from Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the type in either you migration or with the column attribute here is an example:

```
        [Column(TypeName ="sys.Geography")]
        public string Geography { get; set; }
```

With this Update and create work fine, but reading is tricky because EF doesn't won't be able to handle the type. Here is how I get around that mess [altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49735348/7446265).